Calling PyImport_ImportModule with pre-existing Exception condition fails
If PyImport_ImportModule in the Python C API is called from an app using embedded Python when Python is already in an exception state (e.g. from a previous call which set an exception state which has not since been cleared), the method will return null and leave a new exception state which references the original one as cause and context.
I cannot find anything in the documentation which states PyImport_ImportModule will fail under these conditions, nor does the documentation address whether it is valid to make calls to any of the API when in an exception state. It is clearly necessary to be able to do this in some cases (most obviously, to call PyErr_Occurred and examine the resulting exception object).
This does not affect straight Python code, since in that case raising the exception would immediately result in the search for an enclosing try/catch.
I'll admit it is bad practice to allow a lingering exception state to exist (and this has been corrected in the code where I observed this), but I feel either PyImport_ImportModule should work anyway, or the documentation should state that it will fail.
The behaviour actually originates in the function cfunction_call, whose flow is generally
assert(there is no exception state)
call the passed native function
if (there is an exception state) {
    wrap the exception with a new one
    return null
}
else
    return the Python object returned by the native call.

Although there is an assert there it is only helpful if you happen to be embedding a debug build of Python. The presence of the assert implies that this (calling in exception state) is an error.
This could be instead coded as:
save the current exception state if any
call the passed native function
if (there is an exception state && it is different from the one on function entry) {
    wrap the exception with a new one
    return null
}
else
    return the Python object returned by the native call.

but cfunction_call is a general-purpose method and this might cause regressions elsewhere.
This could also be corrected more locally in PyImport_Import by clearing any pre-existing exception state before calling the import function found in __import__ (and, better yet, restoring the exception state if the import itself succeeds so as not to lose information).
But the basic question is whether the code is wrong or the documentation is incomplete.
